# PHP PDO with MSSQL does not reuse prepared statement

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

I have PHP 5.3 with the pdo_sqlsrv extension and a MSSQL2008 database. The following code retrieves data from the table with prepared statement, everything works fine. However, when I repeat the statement several times, in the SQL server profile I can see that the prepared statement is not reused. On every SQL request, the statement is prepared again.

```
    $this->statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT Lang,MemoryArea,ID,TextType,TextValue FROM CoreLanguage WHERE TextType = :textType;");
    $this->statement->bindValue(":textType", "URL");
    $this->statement->execute();
    $data = $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) or array();
    $this->statement->closeCursor();


    $this->statement->bindValue(":textType", "SYSTEM");
    $this->statement->execute();
    $data = $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) or array();
    $this->statement->closeCursor();
```

The reason for this behaviour could be in different string lengths of the variable $textType. As you can see in the profiler list, the same statement is prepared twice with different input parameter data type (nvarchar(6) and nvarchar(3)).

SQL Server Profiler log entry of those data requests:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=2
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(3)',N'SELECT Lang,MemoryArea,ID,TextType,TextValue FROM CoreLanguage WHERE TextType = @P1;',N'URL'
select @p1

declare @p1 int
set @p1=3
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(6)',N'SELECT Lang,MemoryArea,ID,TextType,TextValue FROM CoreLanguage WHERE TextType = @P1;',N'SYSTEM'
select @p1
```

If the input string data is always the same length, the statement is reused by the SQL server. However, that will rarely be the case...

Does anyone know why the SQL server does not reuse the already prepared statement? Or how I could manipulate the input parameter @P1 to a suitable data type, for example nvarchar(40) (same as the TextType column definition)?

Maybe there's a driver specific option that I missed?

Comment: You can try setting the PDO attribute `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to false.

Comment: I tried now to set the attribute before preparing the statement:
`$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` 
This did not change the result. The point is that it works, but only when the parameter string length is exactly the same. Otherwise it creates a new prepared statement because of the different parameter length of @P1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with bindParam() instead of bindValue()? Maybe you can try with that.

Comment: Yes I already tried with bindParam and also its third parameter PDO::PARAM_STR. The result on the sql server is the same.